# How can I call lightning component from Quick Action?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-community

I have a lightning page.I click Edit Page. Now there are multiple sections in which Actions are added.

Now I have to add a button / link which will call a custom lightning component.
I have attached a screenshot. Please have a look at this.

[image]

Comment: your question is not clear - you have added on your page layout a `Related Record` component - do you want to add a button there? you cannot. you can add a button to the sections where all buttons are - on the top right corner - as @gowtham answer

Answer (score -1):

Add this in your component `implements="force:lightningQuickAction"`

[image]